# Can "additionalProperties" apply to nested objects in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm developing an application that accepts the following JSON:

```
{
  "gd": { "enabled": true, "show_counts": true },
  "ra": { "enabled": true }
}
```

I've developed a JSON Schema that validates this input, allowing for some keys to be optional, others required, and some minimum number of properties.  It works well and looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "gd": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "enabled" ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "enabled": { "type": "boolean" },
        "show_counts": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
    },
    "ra": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "enabled" ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "enabled": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
    }
  },
  "minProperties": 1
}
```

One thing that annoys me is that each object redundantly specifies `"additionalProperties": false`.  I would like to specify once, at the top level, that nowhere in the JSON document should any properties not specified in the schema be allowed.

Is that possible?

Comment: Each schema fends on its own. It is designed to allow for additional properties. Disabling them needs to be done in each subschema on its own. Unless you have full control over the places where it is validated, where the validator could specifically enforce this for the whole schema, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest draft (2019-09), you can do this, by defining a "base schema" that all schemas derive from:

```
{
  $defs: {
    base_object: {
      unevaluatedProperties: false
    },
  },
  $ref: '#/$defs/base_object',
  type: 'object',
  // additionalProperties: false does not need to be stated here
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting!  I wonder whether the Python jsonschema 3.2.0 module supports that.

To be clear, do the `$defs` and `$ref` sections need to appear at the beginning of my JSON schema, replacing the current `$schema` property?

Comment: I'm probably wrong with this answer - see https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/910#issuecomment-660247583  -- but no, `$ref` does not replace `$schema` or `$defs`, but is another keyword that lives alongside it, and `$ref` can appear in any subschema, not just at the top level.

Comment: `$defs` replaces `definitions`, which is the reserved location for defining schemas you want to reuse in your schema file.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, you would still need to reference the "base schema" in each of your sub schemas. This isn't a definition which applies to every subschema automatically (there is no such thing)